# Riemann Sums for exponential functions

Tags: riemann-sum

I had a question about Riemann Sums for exponential functions. Function in question is:

$e^{-x^2}$ [More commonly known as the Gaussian Integral.]

The integral from from 0 to 1 (definite integral with the upper limit 1 and the lower limit 0)

Using Riemann Sums, I managed to solve for a specific amount of rectangles. (e.g 5,7,9 etc). However, I wanted to solve for "n" rectangles.

How exactly would I go about doing this? I looked at a couple videos and none of them talk about exponential functions; only polynomials. I know I have to express it as a limit as n goes to infinity but I'm having trouble with it.

I know that $\Delta x$ would be $1/n$. However, I'm having trouble with the rest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter what the function is. The general formula are

$$
I \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
using the left side of rectangles.
$$
I \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$
using the right side of rectangles.

You can average the two to get Trapezoidal integration.

For your problem
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{k}\right) = e^{\frac{-1}{k^2}}
$$

*Added in response to OP's question*

Here are calculations for $N=4$
$$
\frac{ e^{-(1/4)^2}+ e^{-(2/4)^2}+ e^{-(3/4)^2}+ e^{-(4/4)^2}}{4}
\\
\frac{ 0.9394+ 0.7788+ 0.5698+ 0.3679}{4}
= 0.664$$

For $N=6$

$$\frac{ e^{-(1/6)^2}+ e^{-(2/6)^2}+ e^{-(3/6)^2}+ e^{-(4/6)^2}+ e^{-(5/6)^2}+ e^
{-(6/6)^2}}{6}\\
\frac{0.972604+ 0.894839+ 0.778801+ 0.64118+ 0.499352+ 0.367879}{6}
= 0.692443
$$

For $N=8$:
$$
\frac{e^{-(1/8)^2}+ e^{-(2/8)^2}+ e^{-(3/8)^2}+ e^{-(4/8)^2}+ e^{-(5/8)^2}+ e^
{-(6/8)^2}+ e^{-(7/8)^2}+ e^{-(8/8)^2}}{8}
\\
=\frac{0.9845+ 0.9394+ 0.8688+ 0.7788+ 0.6766+ 0.5698+ 0.465+ 0.3679}{8}
= 0.7064
$$

If you look carefully, half the numbers for $N=8$ are already calculated for $N=4$. So if you double $N$, you can save half the calculations.

If you know Richardson Extrapolation, you can *estimate* the limit $N\rightarrow \infty$ easily.

Comment: See thing is, it wouldn't work for me. I need to express it as a limit so something along the lines of:

sigma: (f(xi*)$\Delta x$) ($1/n$)

Comment: @AliImtiaz user44197 really showed you what to do, but perhaps you misunderstood his answer.  He showed you the sums you need and he showed you what terms are under the  $\sum$ sign. When you write $f(x_i)\Delta x(1/n)$ you are actually using $\Delta x$ twice, which is not what you want.  In this case $\Delta x$  and 1/n are the same thing.

Comment: @Betty Mock Thanks Betty.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding how exactly to do this.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Not using a programming language. Doing this by hand. It's for a homework assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The only problem is that I want to do it for "n" intervals and take the limit. Or is it possible to use:
n(n+1)(2n+1)/6
As the above formula allows me to solve for any "n" value.

Comment: If you are doing  by hand, then you can't take the limit. Even $n=10$ gets to be tedious. You can't get an expression for the answer as the integral is not in a closed form. Let me add an edit to my answer as it is too painful to type here

Comment: Never even heard of Richardson Extrapolation. Guess I'll leave it at this. Thanks for all your help!